# Is there a way to extract the 'NAME of the company' 'TITLE of the job' and 'LOCATION of the job' from each line of string below

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, data-processing

From each line of string below, I want to extract company name, job title and location of the job. Is there a way to do so? as the pattern is not consistent. Thanks.

```
"Jerry (YC S17) Is Hiring Senior Software Dev, Data Engineer (Toronto/Remote)"

"Iris Automation Is Hiring an Account Executive for B2B Flying Vehicle Software"

"Strikingly (YC W13) is hiring in our Shanghai office"

"BuildZoom (YC W13) is hiring  help make remodeling cheaper"

"EquipmentShare (YC W15) Is Looking for an Experienced React Native Dev"

"Saleswhale (YC S16) AI Assistant Startup Is Hiring Customer Success Managers"

"Streak (YC S11) is profitable, well funded and hiring in Vancouver"

"Tesorio (YC S15) Is Hiring Engineering Managers, Senior Python Engineer"

"Checkr (YC S14) is hiring engineers to build the future of online trust"

"Rescale Is Hiring a Senior DevOps Engineer in San Francisco"

"Tremendous.com is hiring its first engineer"

"Remix is looking for a front-end engineer to help build better public transit"

"Atomwise (YC W15) Is Hiring a Senior Machine Learning Research Scientist in SF"

"Confident Cannabis (YC S15) Is Hiring Engineers"

"WaystoCap (YC W17) is hiring a software engineer in Spain"

"Smarking (YC W15) Is Hiring a Customer Service Manager"

"Sunsama (YC W19) Is Hiring a Senior Full Stack Engineer (RN/GraphQL/Node)"

"Pachyderm Raised $10M and Is Looking for a Senior Full-Stack Engineer"

"Picktrace (YC S15) is hiring a senior Android engineer"

"Segment is hiring engineers to create our developer platform"

"XIX Is Hiring a Senior Front End Engineer"

"Athelas (YC S16) is hiring software engineers"

"Dyneti (YC W19) is hiring software engineers"

"ZeroCater (YC W11) Is Hiring a Principal Engineer in SF: Must Love Food"

"Mux is looking for developers who want to help developers build better video"

"Munich, Germany: Demodesk (YC W19) Is Hiring Software Engineers"

"New Story (YC Nonprofit) Hiring a JavaScript Software Engineer"

"Quit Genius (YC W18) Is Hiring a Product Manager in London"

"Flexport is hiring senior engineers in SF  Come get to know us"

"OneSignal Is Hiring Ruby on Rails and DevOps Engineers in San Mateo"
```

*************** This is what I want ****************

*Example 1*

"Jerry (YC S17) Is Hiring Senior Software Dev, Data Engineer (Toronto/Remote)"

**Company Name:**  Jerry

**Job Title:** Senior Software Dev, Data Engineer

**Location:** Toronto/Remote

*Example 2*

"Remix is looking for a front-end engineer to help build better public transit"

**Company Name:**  Remix

**Job Title:** front-end engineer

**Location:**

*Example 3*

"Munich, Germany: Demodesk (YC W19) Is Hiring Software Engineers"

**Company Name:**  Demodesk

**Job Title:** Software engineer

**Location:** Munich, Germany

Answer (score 0):

1. Gather a large corpus of examples such as these. 100,000 or so would probably do, but if you can get a million samples, that would be better.
2. Split them manually. If you can afford it, it will be much faster if you distribute the work out to interns/mechanical turk/etc.
3. Train a ML model on your dataset. Don't forget to take a random selection of samples for training/testing. Aim for upwards of 90% accuracy, but also try not to overfit your data.

Comment: In fact, for relatively simple models (e.g. pretrained word embeddings + CRF) much less examples are needed. In my experience, about 1000 examples were already enough to get decent quality. 
As for the exact structure of the model, you can reuse existing architectures for POS tagging.

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge, if the pattern is not consistent than we can not extract and fetch data from the any string.
its can be only done by human being as they have understanding skill, or you need to implement ML.

Answer (score 0):

We can use this models SPACY, CRF, StanfordNLP and LSTM easily. Train 70% and test on 30% data. I prefer Bidirectional-LSTM is best for this.